# How to fast get top N occurence items from an unsorted array in Java?

Tags: java, algorithm, performance, sorting, collections

I've tried two method.

1. use HashMap to count every item's count, then navigate the map

   ```
   HashMap<Integer, Integer> doc_counts = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
   for (int i = 0; i < p; ++i) {
       int doc = alld[i];
       Integer count = doc_counts.get(doc);
       if (null == count)
           count = 0;
       doc_counts.put(doc, count + 1);
   }
   // to now it cost 200ms already
   for (Entry<Integer, Integer> item : doc_counts.entrySet()) {
       heapCheck(h, hsize, item.getKey(), item.getValue());    // heap sort top hsize items
   }
   ```
2. sort the array first, and use heap-sort to get top N.

   ```
   Arrays.sort(alld, 0, p); // the sort costs about 160ms
   int curr = alld[0];
   int count = 0;
   for(int i = 0; i < p; i++) {
       int doc = alld[i];
       if(doc == curr) {
           ++count;
       } else {
           ++nHits;
           //curr += base;
           heapCheck(h, hsize, curr, count);
           curr = doc;
           count = 1;
       }
   }
   //
   // Handle the last document that was collected.
   heapCheck(h, hsize, curr, count);
   ```

Test on a array with 1,600,000 items shows that, the second method cost about 170ms and most all the time is spent on the sort(about 160ms), and the first method cost 200ms even just add all items to the HashMap. How can I improve the performance, find a faster map or sort function or change it to a parallel function to use multithread?

Comment: @assylias The 3 links you referred is on another question 'top N ', but not 'top N occurence'. In fact, the heapCheck is 'top N' problems' best solution, but it's only part of the whole problem.

Comment: Oh sorry I misread your question.

Comment: Have you tried the first with `HashMap<Integer, Integer> doc_counts = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>(alld.length, 1.0f);`?

Comment: @assylias I tried this, and the performance improves little, about 170ms still

Comment: I doubt that you'll be able to find some other algorithm that is less than 10ms slower than Arrays.sort. That seems about as fast as you can get.

Comment: I believe java guarantees a _stable_ sort: equal values remain in the same order. for ints not meaninful. An unstable sort is faster. But if you do your own sorting, you might as well follow the map solution.

Comment: Give us full code listing, please.

Comment: Have you tried using IntMap<Integer> or multisets ? They are not in the Java common library but may be really faster.

Comment: It depends on the size of N.  If N is small then a roughly O(n*N) (where n is array size) solution is probably the best you can do, but as N grows larger (approaching n) the sort scheme will win.

Comment: @HotLicks I think you may misread the question, by the way, N is far smaller than n.

Answer (score 0):

Heap sort is O(n log n) while adding everything to the Hashmap is O(n), so most likely you're suffering constant factor performance hit due to the resizing/rehashing of the Hashmap. Try specifying a large initial capacity to avoid too many resize operations.

Comment: I tried this, and the performance improves little, about 170ms still.

Comment: What if, instead of constantly replacing the integer in the map, you create a mutable `class Count {public int value;}`, then, having found the right instance, increment the count it contains. That will halve the number of map lookups.

Answer (score 0):

The task is well suited to being parallelised. You could use the [FokJoinPool framework](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html) to implement a divide and conquer algorithm. For example, you could use a parallel sort algo to sort your array and reduce the 160ms.

Or if you want to experiment with Java 8, it has a built-in `Arrays.parallelSort()` method.

Answer (score 0):

The `Collection` framework with primitive types is really expensive.

Try using [GNU Trove](http://trove.starlight-systems.com/) `TIntIntHashMap` instead for the first approach, the counting map.

In my opinion and experience, the second should be faster, in particular if you already have the data in memory anyway, and can use primitive sorting, which is a lot faster than sorting objects.

Answer (score 0):

Don't sort - that's O(n log n). There's an O(n) + O(N log N) solution:

- Create a `Map<Integer, Integer>` to hold the count for each number O(n)
- Make one pass over the array creating/updating the counts O(n)
- Make one pass over the map keeping the top N largest, probably using a Navigable map O(N log N)

If N << n, it's O(n). If N ≈ n, it's O(N log N)